# Pulling image from local docker insecured Docker registry to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, docker-toolbox, minikube

**Cannot pull image from local docker insecured registry repository inside Minikube.**
I'm running Docker-toolbox v1.12.2 using Linux VM (Upstart) installed on Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.6 under Windows 7.

I've created a docker image and push (tag and then push) it into a local insecured docker-registry v2 that running on 192.168.99.100:5000/image/name.
`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`
and inside the VM, on /var/lib/boot2docker/profile I've add to the EXTRA_ARGS the flag 
`--insecure-registry 192.168.99.100:5000` .

`docker push` & `docker pull` from `localhost:5000/image/name` are working fine within Docker(VM).
 
_catalog is reachable from Postman :`GET http:192.168.99.100:5000/v2/_catalog` and I'm able to get the images inside the registry.

I'm starting my Minikube v0.15.0 VM with the command:

`minikube start --insecure-registry=192.168.99.100:5000`

**I'm under company PROXY** so I've added the proxy in the command line (CMD):
`set HTTP/HTTPS_PROXY=my.company.proxy:8080` and `set NO_PROXY={minikube ip}`.
Then Kubernetes dashboard started to work for me.

Now for the real problem, when running the command:
`kubectl run image-name --image=192.168.99.100:5000/image/name --port=9999`
to pull image from my local docker registry into Kubernetes its saying

> deployment "image-name" created

But inside Kubernetes > Deployments I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to pull image "192.168.99.109:5000/image/name": image pull failed for 192.168.99.100:5000/image/name:latest, this may be because there are no credentials on this request. details: (Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.99.100:5000/v1/_ping: Tunnel or SSL Forbidden)

Can anyone help here with that **Tunnel or SSL Forbidden error**, it's driving me crazy, and I've tried so many solutions to configure --insecrue-registery inside docker, inside Kubernetes or when running the dokcer-registry.

BTW why it's refering to v1/_ping? i'm using the docker registry v2.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like minikube cannot see the same network that your registry is running. Can you try running `minikube ssh` then run your curl for the catalog?

Also, as an alternative, you could run `eval(minikube docker-env)` which then will set your local docker client to use the docker server inside minikube.

So for example if you built an image tagged with `myimage/foo` it would build and put that image on the minikube docker host, so when you deployed the image, it wouldn't need to be pulled.

Comment: I can't curl to the catalog from inside the minikube. the registry and minikube are running on separeted VM's inside virtualBox, maybe i neewd to configure somthing there?

Comment: Yup sounds like your problem. You should be able to attach both VM's to the same network.